# Exploding a doughnut chart's slice

Tags: chart-design

I've a fairly simple doughnut chart drawer application which can produce charts like this below:

[image]

Only one thing is missing now, I'd like to *explode* its slices (only one at-a-time) to show if a slice has been selected.

My idea was to explode them by transforming the slice's inner and outer circles' origos towards slice's middle point. This works pretty good for smaller slices:

[image]

But for a larger slice (larger or equal than PI), it looks strange:

[image]

Especially if I put it into a circle context (eg.: a circle display):

[image] [image]

What can I do to improve those larger slices' look and feel?

Comment: This chart might help: https://evolytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Should-I-use-a-pie-chart.png

Comment: See also https://klmr.me/pie

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of shifting shapes laterally away from the centre of the circle, imagine moving them towards the viewer.

Just scale the slices up with the centre of the scaling aligned with the middle of the doughnut. Effects like drop shadows will help. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Which is the same as increasing the inner and outer radius

Comment: That is a really nice effect. Well done!

Comment: How should the pointer targeting work in this situation? If I hover my mouse over the inner edge of a slice, then the slice "pops" away such that my mouse is no longer on top of it. Enlarging the outer radius while keeping the inner one the same would fix this, but maybe it looks weird?

Comment: For my situation (there is no mouse or pointer at all), this is not an issue. Keeping the inner and enlarging the outer can help you, but I have tried that before asking here and honestly it looks really weird compared to this one.

Comment: Btw, what is your intention behind popping out on mouse hover/click? What is the benefit? If you navigate to over a slice with your mouse you must already know which one is selected, no need to pop it out imho.

Comment: @Max Good question. I think the answer is to have a hidden area that handles mouse events. In the normal state, it will coincide with the slice, but when a mouseover occurs, expand its outer radius so that it covers the original and zoomed shapes. Shouldn't be too hard to implement, but you'd have to ask at Stackoverflow if you need help :-)

Comment: Oh, I was just asking out of idle curiosity—mercifully for the end users of the world, I am not a graphic designer  And I agree with @Daniel that this is probably not the best choice for a pointer or touchscreen interface—in that case just highlighting the selection without popping it out is probably sufficient.